# Problem understanding CT output

Tags: voltage, transformer, inductor, current-measurement, current-transformer

I was trying to measure the current of the AC line using CT. As I haven't used CT before, I thought that the output of the CT will be sinusoidal for a resistive load on the mainline. But the actual output was totally different from sinusoidal.

[image]

The circuit is simple. 220 volts main is stepped down into 24 volts and connected to 833-ohm resistance.

[image]

**How can I measure instantaneous current using CT? Is it possible to apply any higher-order regression to calculate the instantaneous current?** Not just the peak value. At least 30 samples per cycle. The CT used here is 5A/5mA.

**Problem Solved**
As @Andy said to insert a burden load, so I checked that. I connected a 220-ohm resistor to the CT. And the output was sinusoidal.
[image]

Comment: Please link to the data sheet for the CT. Also provide a schematic of your secondary side circuit used and where your connected the probes.

Comment: I haven't found the datasheet of it. I purchased it from an online store. Although there's some datasheet of 5A / mA CT in google, my CT doesn't have any model number written in the body.

Comment: 24 V into 800 Ohm is only 30 mA, so your CT should give you just 30 uA. How are you measuring that? What burden resistor are you using? Your scope says 1.76 V RMS which implies 56k, but it should be 10 or 100 Ohms or so. (then you need to measure the 300 uV, difficult). If you want to measure 30 mA then this is the wrong CT. Or, rather test it with a light bulb drawing 0.5 A or more. Loop it through the CT a few times too.

Comment: Just one info is given. 5A/5mA. Nothing more than this.

Comment: Ok, I'll test it on an AC lamp. It will take some time to make the setup.

Comment: No datasheet, no sale. Applies to CTs too. Try a burden resistor as Andy says, and Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More than likely you need to fit a burden resistor to the CT output. Typical for this size current transformer is 100 ohm but smaller is better. Without a CT burden resistor you can get core saturation and strange looking voltage waveforms.

Comment: @relayman357 correct and correcting.

Comment: I connected 100 ohms. The output was pure sine, although the amplitude was very small. So I connected 220. The output is still good. I have attached a screenshot at the description of the question.

Comment: You shouldn't call it a dummy load (unless you want to sound like a dummy LOL) - it has a proper name and it is called "a burden" resistor. No CT can operate correctly without one and the lower the value the more accurate the CT will be for an application. If this means a lower output voltage then it also means a purer waveform and a waveform more representative of the current in the primary. If necessary use an op-amp to buffer and amplify.